# Java Scanner is requiring multiple entries

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

The following is some code I wrote in Java for setting up a player in a game. The scanners I set up for atk, def, and hp are requiring 2-3 entries. I apologize for the messy code, I am just beginning to learn Java.

```
String NAME;
int ATK;
int DEF;
int HP;
int remainingPoints = 10;
// pick name
System.out.println("Enter name:");
Scanner p2Name = new Scanner(System.in);
NAME = p2Name.nextLine();
// pick type
System.out.println("Choose element theme: (water,fire,ice)");
Scanner p2Type = new Scanner(System.in);
String TYPE = p2Type.nextLine();
// atk
System.out.println("You have ten points to disperse " + "among your atk, def and hp");
System.out.println("Enter atk:");
Scanner p2Atk = new Scanner(System.in);
if (p2Atk.nextInt() <= 10) {
    ATK = p2Atk.nextInt();
    remainingPoints = remainingPoints - ATK;
} else {
    System.out.println("Your entry was invalid, your " + "atk is now five by default.");
    ATK = 5;
    remainingPoints = remainingPoints - ATK;
}
// def
System.out.println("You now have " + remainingPoints + ". Please enter def:");
Scanner p2Def = new Scanner(System.in);
if (p2Def.nextInt() <= remainingPoints) {
    remainingPoints = remainingPoints - p2Def.nextInt();
    DEF = p2Def.nextInt();
} else {
    System.out.println("Your entry was invalid, your " + "def is now one by default.");
    DEF = 1;
    remainingPoints = remainingPoints - DEF;
}
// hp
System.out.println("You now have " + remainingPoints + ". Please enter hp:");
Scanner p2Hp = new Scanner(System.in);
if (p2Hp.nextInt() <= remainingPoints) {
    remainingPoints = remainingPoints - p2Hp.nextInt();
    HP = p2Hp.nextInt();
} else {
    System.out.println("Your entry was invalid, your " + "hp is now one by default.");
    HP = 1;
    remainingPoints = remainingPoints - HP;
}
Player p2 = new Player(NAME, TYPE, ATK, DEF, HP);
System.out.println(p2.n);
System.out.println(p2.type);
System.out.println(p2.atk);
System.out.println(p2.def);
System.out.println(p2.hp);
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Why are you creating multiple `Scanner` objects?

Comment: Holy code-formatting Batman! That's a wall of text that needs editing!

Comment: Just saying, when you are "just learning Java", by not setting yourself up with good code-formatting/writing habits from the start you are doing yourself a real disservice.   I would highly suggest fixing the formatting of your code, regardless of skill-level.

Answer (score 2):

There is no need to create a new Scanner object every time you prompt for an input.

The data type you are prompting to input, be it an `int`, `double` or `String`, you only need to create the Scanner object **once** - i.e.: for `system.in`.

However beginners in Java may encounter a problem when using `scn.nextInt()`.
You may place a `scn.nextLine()` after prompting to solve that problem.

But personally I prefer to receive every input as `String` using `scn.nextLine()`. If it is an `int` input, just do:

```
int num = Integer.parseInt(scn.nextLine());
```

---

**Example:**

```
Scanner scn = new Scanner(System.in);

String name = scn.nextLine();
String type = scn.nextLine();
String spell = scn.nextLine();
int health = Integer.parseInt(scn.nextLine());
```

Comment: *"However beginners in Java may encounter a problem when using `scn.nextInt()`. You may place a `scn.next()` after prompting to solve that problem."* a `next()` call won't solve that problem, because it doesn't consume the "new line" delimiter if there is not another token "behind" it.

Answer (score 1):

You have created too many Scanner objects which is not right.

About requiring 2-3 entries - you should put value in a temp variable once and then use it n number of times.

PFB corrected code:

```
String NAME = null;
String TYPE = null;
int ATK = 0;
int DEF = 0;
int HP = 0;
int remainingPoints = 10;

try {

    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Enter name:");
    NAME = scanner.nextLine();

    System.out.println("Choose element theme: (water,fire,ice)");
    TYPE = scanner.nextLine();

    System.out.println("You have ten points to disperse "
            + "among your atk, def and hp");

    System.out.println("Enter atk:");
    int temp = scanner.nextInt();

    if (temp <= 10)
        ATK = temp;
    else {
        System.out.println("Your entry was invalid, your "
                + "atk is now five by default.");
        ATK = 5;
    }

    remainingPoints = remainingPoints - ATK;
    System.out.println("You now have " + remainingPoints
            + ". Please enter def:");           

    temp = scanner.nextInt();
    if (temp <= remainingPoints)
        DEF = temp;
    else {
        System.out.println("Your entry was invalid, your "
                + "def is now one by default.");
        DEF = 1;
    }
    remainingPoints = remainingPoints - DEF;
    System.out.println("You now have " + remainingPoints
            + ". Please enter hp:");

    temp = scanner.nextInt();
    if (temp <= remainingPoints)
        HP = temp;
    else {
        System.out.println("Your entry was invalid, your "
                + "hp is now one by default.");
        HP = 1;
    }
    remainingPoints = remainingPoints - HP;

    scanner.close();
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

Player p2 = new Player(NAME, TYPE, ATK, DEF, HP);

System.out.println(p2.n);
System.out.println(p2.type);
System.out.println(p2.atk);
System.out.println(p2.def);
System.out.println(p2.hp);
```

Comment: Is there a reason for calling `scanner.close();` in your code?

Comment: It's good practice to always close your scanners when you are through with them @Tom

Comment: @EvanBechtol You think OP is through with `System.in` so you can close that stream? I don't think so, since this code is only used for setting up a player for the game, it is highly possible, that OP likes to get more user input during this game, so it is _very wrong_ to close that scanner.

Comment: Good point! If he plans in getting more input, he shouldn't close. But, at the end of his game, he should close it.

Comment: @EvanBechtol If he is absolutly sure, that there is no more need for `System.in`, then yes he should clean up his used resources.